# How to create bi-weekly pay schedule based on given month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a monthly budget for my family and I want to be able to show expected pay dates given the current month.  One person gets paid weekly, on Thursdays so I simply used

```
=DATE(YEAR(F1),MONTH(F1),1+1*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(year(F1),month(F1),8-5))
```

where F1 is the 1st of the Month I manually type in for which I am budgeting for.

Since there is not always the 5th Thursday I wrote an if statement that would enter the date of the 5th Thursday of that month if existed, but if not would then populate as "Total:" (the pay was calculated in next column similarly).  This way if there was the 5th Thursday, the date would populate and a row below it would be "Total:", but if not, then that 5th Thursday cell would populate as "Total:". (C9 is 4th Thursdays date)

```
=if(C9+7>=F1+31,"Total:",DATE(YEAR(F1),MONTH(F1),1+5*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(year(F1),month(F1),8-5)))
```

Now, I want to do the same thing, but for a bi-weekly basis.  That is I want pay dates to appear given a certain month on a bi-weekly schedule, but only if they are within that month.  Example: For May in particular payday is on  5/10/19 and then the next 5/24/19 (two weeks every Friday).

So my issue is how, when I the F1 date for a new month, can I get this populate correctly given that it can be the first or second Friday of any given month depending on when the payday happens.  I also want to do the same sort of calculating based on whether they would get paid two or three times in a month, i.e., it doesn't populate if it is only two times but will if three.

Bonus:  Is there a way to have Google Sheets automatically duplicate a sheet (perhaps even name it and/or change a cell value(F1)) on a specific day of the month? Let's say... the 27th of every month.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jLqQKNHzHE8QOGpyTdD1jXrbRzgq1mWHqjuYdzei1sE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TEXT(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1), 0)))), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1), 0)))), "ddd"),
 "Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Sat|Sun", "♠")<>"♠"), "dd-mmm-yyyy"), 
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1), 0)))), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), 1), 0)))), "ddd"),
 "Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Sat|Sun", "♠")<>"♠"))+1)), 2)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works for May, but when I put in June for the date it shows June 14th and 28th when it should be June 7th and 21st since two weeks from May 24th is June 7th.

Comment: this formula does not accounts with previous months. it shows only every 2nd Friday in every given month eg 14 and 28 is correct

Comment: if you want to irritate every 2nd Friday across multiple months you will need to specify the end date